# JavaScript document.execCommand() own tags

Tags: javascript, html, execcommand

I've found some really interesting! The execCommand function applies many useful features. But is it possible to work with OWN wraps? Like:

```
document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", false, "<span class='own-class'>");
```

Everything related i've found was pretty old… so maybe one of you knows a good workaround or something.

Comment: wrap the tags around the selection then use the "insertHTML" command.

Comment: already tried and didn't get it. Any link or something useful?

Comment: document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<span class='own-class'>"+ document.getSelection()+"</span>"); works for me in chrome...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Thanks to dandavis.

The following works very well:

```
document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<span class='own-class'>"+ document.getSelection()+"</span>");
```

Comment: @dandavis but... this strips all existing tags from the selection!

Comment: Potential problem: This removes all newlines from the selected text.