# How to replace selected text on page with another text?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to replace selected text with another text with a function **switchText** called from the context menu.

```
function switchText(info) {

var text = info.selectionText;     // selected text

// then I do some manipulations with 'text' and get 'text_to_replace'

var text_to_replace = "some text"; // text to replace

}
```

**alert(text)** and **alert(text_to_replace)** works fine, but I'm trying to replace selected text right on the page but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried different methods but they hadn't worked. Any special permissions needed? I'm sorry if it's stupid question, I'm beginner in JS.

Comment: The text is coming to an html element?

Comment: The text can be in any html element. Any text selected with mouse

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to do this anywhere on a page, you need to be able to set some kind of identifying ID to your selection. You have to do this through a content script of some kind. You can read more about it in the [Chrome Developer documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).

### This code will allow you to change the text of a single selection

*(tested in Chrome only)*

```
function switchText(id) {
    // Gets the selection range
    // This is from Tim Down, linked below
    var range, sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    // Creates a new node range
    document.designMode = "on";
    if (range) {
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    // This is from user YeppThatsMe, also linked below
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<span id='own-id'>"+ document.getSelection()+"</span>");

    document.designMode = "off";

    // You can use either a variable or a string
    var someNewText = "-- You can make this whatever you want --";

    // Finds the new span and replaces the selection with your new text
    document.getElementById("own-id").innerHTML=someNewText;
};
```

### Sourced scripts

[Tim's script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582831/how-can-i-highlight-the-text-of-the-dom-range-object/2583895#2583895)

[HTML5 inserCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529316/javascript-document-execcommand-own-tags)

### Last Note

I didn't spend too long testing, and the script as-is will only change one selection per page. You'll need to tweak the way the function gets the tag and attribute info (change it to `getElementsByClassName`?) to run it more than once, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

to update a html element targeted by Id

```
document.getElementById("idtotarget").innerHTML = switchText(document.getElementById("idtotarget").innerHTML)
```

Comment: I don't have specific ID, the selected text can be anywhere on any page.