# Add tags around selected text in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add `<span>` tags around selected text within an element?

For example, if somebody highlights "John", I would like to add span tags around it.

HTML

```
<p>My name is Jimmy John, and I hate sandwiches. My name is still Jimmy John.</p>
```

JS

```
function getSelectedText() {
  t = (document.all) ? document.selection.createRange().text : document.getSelection();

  return t;
}

$('p').mouseup(function(){
    var selection = getSelectedText();
    var selection_text = selection.toString();
    console.log(selection);
    console.log(selection_text);

    // How do I add a span around the selected text?
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2w35p/

There is a identical question here: [jQuery select text and add span to it in an paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236982/jquery-select-text-and-add-span-to-it-in-an-paragraph), but it uses outdated jquery methods (e.g. live), and the accepted answer has a bug.

Comment: A lot can go wrong when selection starts in one element and ends in another. It would be nice if you could specify which behavior you'd like in that case (e.g. don't do anything, or create as many span elements as necessary in order to properly wrap the selection).

Comment: Let's go with "dont do anything" if it spans multiple elements. Once we solve that (which also happens to work for my particular use case), someone can attempt the harder one where it spans multiple elements.

Comment: BTW, if you share your actual goal, there will most likely be a less error-prone approach.

Comment: When I'm working with selections, I usually use [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/). See the [CSS Class Applier demo](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/cssclassapplier.html) which wraps the selection into `<span>`s with a given class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a solution. Get the `Range` of the selecion and deleteContent of it, then insert a new `span` in it .

```
$('body').mouseup(function(){
    var selection = getSelectedText();
    var selection_text = selection.toString();

    // How do I add a span around the selected text?

    var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
    span.textContent = selection_text;

    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(span);
});
```

You can see the [DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/edisonator/2w35p/35/)

**UPDATE**

Absolutly, the selection will be delete at the same time. So you can add the selection range with js code if you want.

Comment: but this doesn't work when I have a header tags along with paragraph tags as it doesn't return the same format as the selected text.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do like this.

```
$('body').mouseup(function(){
   var span = document.createElement("span");
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.surroundContents(span);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2w35p/40/)

Reference [Wrapping a selected text node with span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/wrapping-a-selected-text-node-with-span)

Comment: Your anwser is better than mine! It's gorgeous!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('body').mouseup(function(){
   var selection = getSelectedText();
   var innerHTML = $('p').html();
   var selectionWithSpan = '<span>'+selection+'</span>';
   innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(selection,selectionWithSpan);
   $('p').html(innerHTML);    
});
```

and In your `fiddle` you are again opening a new `<p>` instead of a closing `</p>`. Update that please.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for repeated selection text (e.g. `the person wrote the code`, highlight `the`).

Answer (score 0):

**THIS WORKS** (*mostly**)!! (technically, it does what you want, but it needs HALP!)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5arj/)

This adds `<span ...>` and `</span>` correctly, *even* if there are multiple instances of the selection in your element and you only care about the instance that's selected!

**It works perfectly the first time** if you include my commented line. It's after that when things get funky.

I can add the span tags, but I'm having a hard time replacing the plaintext with html. Maybe you can figure it out? We're almost there!! This uses nodes from `getSelection`. Nodes can be hard to work with though.

```
document.getElementById('d').addEventListener('mouseup',function(e){
    var s = window.getSelection();
    var n = s.anchorNode; //DOM node
    var o = s.anchorOffset; //index of start selection in the node
    var f = s.focusOffset; //index of end selection in the node
    n.textContent = n.textContent.substring(0,o)+'<span style="color:red;">'
        +n.textContent.substring(o,f)+'</span>'
        +n.textContent.substring(f,n.textContent.length);
        //adds the span tag
    // document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = n.textContent;
    // this line messes stuff up because of the difference 
    // between a node's textContent and it's innerHTML.
});
```