# How to change styles of user highlighted text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, highlight, rich-text-editor

I am looking for a way to change the style of the text highlighted from the user. For example when the user highlights text with their mouse and clicks a button, I want the text that is selected to change even after it is not being highlighted anymore like a rich text editor. I tried to store the highlighted text into a variable and change the styles with the javascript DOM style property but it it returns an error. Here is my code so far

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {  
    if(window.getSelection().toString().length){
       let exactText = window.getSelection().toString();        
    }
}
```

It can `console.log` the text that is highlighted but it can't change the styles. Thank you for your help

Comment: You probably want to wrap the text with a span element or something to be able to apply styles. This gets complicated, though, when you overlap other tags in the document.

Comment: Oh ok, Do you know any way you to do that. Thanks!

Comment: I thinkб this topic can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690357/add-tags-around-selected-text-in-an-element

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.